# С чего начать изучение API?

Tags: java, android, asp.net

У меня такая ситуация,  У нас есть 1  урок по ASP.Net и другой урок по разработке Android приложений, и я хочу написать веб  приложение на ASP и его мобильное прил. для Android. И препод  говорит что можно просто добавить API от веб приложения в мобилку и чтоб  вся обработка шла туда. То есть  написать бэк-енд на ASP и использовать его и в мобильном андроид  приложении(хотя бэк Андроида вроде на Java). Как это сделать или как правильно задавать вопросы гуглу или как искать уроки по этой теме ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если вы будете самостоятельно писать бэк для своего приложения то начинать нужно с изучения всего что связано с серверной частью. Если же вам уже будут давать готовое апи для вашего приложения, то нужно начинать изучать принципы отправки запросов на сервер и обработки его ответов. Я на данный момент занимаюсь разработкой клиент-серверного приложения, и мне дают документацию по апи, где прописаны все запросы необходимые для полного замещения веб-сервиса моим приложением. Для работы с апи я использую библиотеку `Retrofit`, хотя есть и `Volley` - это уже кому какая придется по душе. Лично я бы вам советовал начать читать про сами клиент-серверные приложения. Библиотеку я вам посоветую использовать `Retrofit` потому-что она более удобная и гибкая, и лично мне более понятна в использовании. Ниже я привожу несколько ссылок которые облегчат выполнение ваших задач:

1. [Инструмент](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) для создания классов-моделей, которые будут использоваться в запросах.
2. [Сервис](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/), который показывает структуру вашего ответа с сервера.
3. [Туториал](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) для работы с ретрофитом.
4. [Статья](https://habr.com/post/281965/) по библиотекам которые я указывал.
5. [Еще статья](https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial) по работе с `retrofit`

Надеюсь хоть чем-то помог, если будет что-то не понятно - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте. Удачи, я верю что у вас все получится :)

Comment: Спасибо,  попробую все что вы написали )

Comment: Еще добавил бы https://hurl.quickblox.com для отправки запросов с компа, так быстрее иногда

Comment: @Романыч, ссылка не работает почему-то)

Comment: Извиняюсь за нерабочую ссылку, так добавил бы программу PostMan для PC , удобно отправлять запросы и смотреть ответ. Мне помогает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый пожалуйста.