# Как реализовать запрос на сервер?

Tags: android

меня интересует следующий вопрос: каким образом реализуется запрос из приложения на сервер? Например: раз в 10 секунд.

Не могли бы Вы предоставить пример?

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы сделать запрос на сервер вам нужно изучить клиент-серверную архитектуру мобильных приложений. Вот например есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883391/%D0%A1-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-api/883399#883399) по вашей тематике. Раз в 10 секунд слать запрос из приложения это конечно интересно, но мне кажется вы имели в виду обмен данными в фоне, а для этого вам нужно сделать сервис который будет работать даже после того как приложение закрыто. Вот ответ на ваш вопрос - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617621/android-how-to-send-http-request-via-service-every-10-seconds).