# Отправка данных на сервер | Android, Java

Tags: java, android, http, веб-сервер

Необходимо реализовать отправку данных на http сервер. Как это можно реализовать на java, в android приложении?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще данные отправляются на сервер типом запроса - POST. Для того чтобы вам его отправить вам нужно организовать запрос и вкинуть в тело запроса данные. Но как-бы вы не слали запрос, вам нужно знать что сервер что-то ответит в итоге. Если вам дали апи например то это облегчает вам задачу намного, но если вам нужно еще и само апи писать - это сложновато будет. Вот например есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883391/%D0%A1-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-api/883399#883399). Вам необходимо будет отправлять на сервер данные в определенном формате и на определенный адрес сервера. Если возникнут вопросы или что-то останется непонятным, то не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, постараюсь помочь чем смогу. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо, что пытаетесь мне помочь! Я не очень понимаю, почему сервер должен мне что то вернуть если я шлю ему POST запрос?

Comment: Допустим, я отправляю какие то данные которые выбрал пользователь в предложенной форме на сервер, что в этом случае сервер должен вернуть обратно?

Comment: обратно вам сервер вернет ответ с нужными вам данными.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый