# Приложение для Android на базе сайта. Какие технологии использовать?

Tags: android, webview

Имеется сайт. Это доска объявлений (категории, карточка объявления, фильтр, форма подачи объявления). Необходимо сделать приложение для сайта (просмотр карточки объявления, категорий, возможность подачи объявления из приложения).
С разработкой под Android столкнулся впервые. Узнал о том, что есть в android есть webView. Пришла идея сделать отдельно упрощённую версию сайта на Vue.JS и отображать его в приложении при помощи webView. Вроде данное решение самое простое, но мне кажется, что если требования к приложению будут увеличиваться, то с этим webView будет много проблем в дальнейшем.
Второй вариант, использовать RestApi. В принципе данные передавать на сервер и получать не так и сложно. Но встаёт вопрос о том, как динамически отрисовывать элементы во View на основе полученных данных. Ведь в категории может быть и 3 объявления, а может быть и 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема WebView в том что этот виджет очень плохо отображает сайты. Даже если подключить все плюшки (JS и тд.) то все-равно много чего виджет не сможет корректно отобразить, будут проблемы с загрузкой стилей и шрифтов, будет много сложностей, и от них никак не избавится.

Мой вам совет - используйте Rest API. Это самое идеальное решение для приложений которые делаются по сайту. Для этого апи есть две основные библиотеки которые упрощают обращение к серверу и разработка такого приложения не очень сложная. Вот например есть [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883391/%D0%A1-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-api/883399#883399) по работе с апи. Вы сможете передавать с сервера любые данные касательно объявления и отображать как вам будет угодно. Дальше по поводу динамического отображения - если вам нужно сделать отображение в реальном времени, то можно сделать функцию для отправки запроса например раз в 5-10 секунд. Но не очень понятно что значит для вас динамически. Если например в категории у вас есть 10 объявлений, то вам сервер передаст эти 10 объявлений, если 1000 - то 1000. Вопрос в том как вы хотите их отобразить. Можно отображать на стр. 10-20 объявлений, и тогда советую изучить библиотеку от Google по paging.

Если возникнут какие-то дополнительные вопросы - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, поможем чем сможем. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо. 
1)Нужно отображение в реальном времени (и возможно кеш последних объявлений, если в данный момент нет интернета)
2) Динамически, имею в виду, что на сайте  во вьюшках можно вставлять foreach(){ } и внутри его выводить блоки объявления. Как похожее реализовать в Android? Я ведь в layout не могу писать java код.
3) Скорее всего постраничная навигация

Comment: 1. в кеш можете сохранить конечно, но все зависит от кол-ва объявлений. 2. не очень понял так как с версткой не очень знаком. 3. для постраничной навигации просто нужно будет добавлять параметры  в запрос и все, ничего сложного.

Answer (score 6):

Приложения нужно разрабатывать индивидуальное со всеми функциями. Приложения с использованием одного webView получит бан на плеймаркете. Так как оно не будет соответствовать требованиям. Думаю в этой статье можно найти всю нужную информацию и ссылки [Ссылка на статью habr](https://habr.com/ru/company/livetyping/blog/326874/)

Comment: раз дали ответ укажите ссылку на требование, всем будет удобно